# Error sending HTML mails with Agents in LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to send emails from agents, but i have an error always with the next document that the agent process.

For example, if there are 5 emails to send, the first is ok, but with the second the agent stops and show this error:

> Objet variable not set

The code:

```
Sub Initialize
    
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim ns As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim docs As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim mh As NotesMIMEHeader
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim formula As String
    Dim header As String
    Dim body2 As String
    
    Set db = ns.CurrentDatabase
    Set maildoc = db.Createdocument
    'Set doc = ws.Currentdocument.Document
    Set stream = ns.Createstream()
    header = "Test Agent"
    body2 = "Test Agent"
    
    ' Create the MIME headers
    Set body = maildoc.CreateMIMEEntity
    Set mh = body.CreateHeader("Subject")
    
    ' Dont convert text to rich text
    ns.Convertmime = False
    
    ' Configure the mail
    maildoc.Form = "Memo"
    maildoc.Subject = "Test Agent"
    maildoc.SendTo = "Email Destination"
    maildoc.CopyTo = ""
    maildoc.blindCopyTo = ""
    
    Dim dateObj As New NotesDateTime("")
    '@Adjust( fecha-hora ; años ; meses ; días ; horas ; minutos ; segundos ; [ DST ] )
    
    formula = "(Form = ""frm-testdevelop-solicitud"") & (Estado = ""Borrador"")" 
    
    Set docs = db.Search(formula, Nothing, 0)
    
    If docs.count > 0 Then
        
        Print "hay " + Cstr(docs.count) + " docs"
        Set doc = docs.GetFirstDocument
        
        While Not doc Is Nothing

            Call stream.Writetext(|<html lang="es">|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<head>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|</head>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<body>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<div style="background-color: #897d7d; border-radius: 0.5em; width: auto; height: 50px;">
                                <h1 style="color: white; text-align: center; padding: 0.1em;
                                font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;">| & header & |</h1>
                                </div>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|<p>| & body2 & |</p>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|</body>|)
            Call stream.Writetext(|</html>|)
            Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, {text/html;charset="utf-8"}, ENC_NONE)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            Here is the error in the second iterate.

            ' Close the stream
            Call stream.Close()
            
            ' Restore conversion
            ns.Convertmime = True
            
            ' Send it
            Call maildoc.Send(False)

            ' Next document
            Set doc = docs.GetNextDocument(doc)
            
        Wend
    Else
        Print "No hay documentos"   
    End If
```

Exit Sub

In the second iterate the agent stop in this part of the code:

> Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, {text/html;charset="utf-8"}, ENC_NONE)

I know that the error is because I am sending this email with HTML format, because if I remove the sendemail block of code, the agents runs fine.

And I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any suggest?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every run you add the new content to the stream. As you do not "Open" a file with your stream, the "close" in your code does not do anything.

Replace the "stream.close" with a "stream.truncate" to remove the contents. That should do the trick.